# Is there a way to use CoreML models in capacitor-plugins?

Tags: swift, ionic-framework, capacitor, coreml, capacitor-plugin

I am currently working on a capacitor plugin, that should allow me to run a CoreML-model on the ios-version of my Ionic-App.

Even though I used the common terminology to access the model-file, the model is somehow not found in my ios-plugin-script. Is there a different way I can access the model besides VNCoreMLModel or is there maybe in general a problem with using CoreML models in capacitor plugins?

I also tried to load the model, using the same lines of code in a full/native swift app, what worked fine.

The model is already located in the Plugins' Directory (together with the files Plugin.swift, Plugin.m and so on...) and is accessed via calling it as //VNCoreMLModel(for: "modelname".model).

The error message in particular is : "Cannot find 'Resnet50' in scope"

code snippet:

```
guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50().model) else {return}
```

(I personally think, that when integrating the plugin into my app, the model file is  maybe not transferred into the 'Development Pods' for any reason.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what capacitor is, but `Resnet50` is a class that is automatically generated by Xcode. You either need to copy the source code for that class into your own project, or not use that class and instantiate an `MLModel` object for your model instead.